# How to automate testing a document

Tags: automation, automated-tests

Need to automate testing of Docusign documents which has lot of fields.

Any suggestions what is the best aprroach for this?

Should I use Java or Selenium?

Comment: FWIW: [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) can programmatically drive a browser, and it supports a number of languages, including Java.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web page you can use Selenium to automate it.
Since Selenium is suitable for most (popular) programming languages you can choose the one you know better. Java is just one of the options.